# .htaccess password requested twice when redirected, not requested/site Unauthorized on mobile

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate, password-protection, http-redirect

I'm trying to user .htaccess for both SSL redirects and Password authentication.

1. when requesting http://example.com, user is asked to login, is then redirected to http**s**://example.com, and asked to login again. How can I prevent this double authentication?
2. on iphone, the user is not asked for a password at all but merely served a 401 "Unauthorized" error. Why is ios not giving user opportunity to enter password?

   ErrorDocument 401 default

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Please enter password to proceed"
   AuthUserFile /home/example/public_html/.htpasswd
   require valid-user

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]

Thank you for your time!